# Align a figure with a bullet

Tags: floats, itemize

I want to align vertically a figure inside a itemize environment.
The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\begin{document}

I want the bullet vertically aligned with the picture

\begin{itemize}
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{paris.jpg}
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{paris.jpg}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

whose the output is:

[image]

But the bullet are in the bottom of the figure. How can I center at left of the figure?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `valign` option from the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

I want the bullet vertically aligned with the picture

\begin{itemize}
    \item \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    \item \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\hbox` inside `\vcenter`. Put it in a macro for ease of use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\newcommand{\igcenter}[2][1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}}}$}

\begin{document}

I want the bullet vertically aligned with the picture

\begin{itemize}
    \item \igcenter[0.1]{example-image-a}
    \item \igcenter[0.1]{example-image-b}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```